# Failed to produce diagnostic for expression

Tags: swift, debugging, mvvm, swiftui

im new at SwiftUI, i'm trying to implement a list of views and i got this (i guess) syntax error, can't find it, maybe someone can explain ?

I have a model for my venues:

```
struct Venue: Codable {
    let venueId: String
    let name: String
    let location: Location
    let categories: [VenueCategory]?

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case venueId = "id"
        case name
        case location
        case categories
    }
}
```

Then custom view, which i want to list:

```
struct VenueItemView: View {
    @Binding var venue : Venue
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("\(venue.name)")
    }
}
```

ViewModel, wheare i store Venues:

```
import Foundation
import FoursquareAPIClient

class FeedViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var venues: [Venue] = FoursquareManager.sharedManager().venues
}
```

And main view, wheare i got this error:

```
import SwiftUI

struct FeedView: View {
    @StateObject private var viewModel = FeedViewModel()
    
    var body: some View { // Failed to produce diagnostic for expression
        Text("Hello")
        List(viewModel.venues) { v in
            VenueItemView(venue: binding(for: v))
        }
    }
    
    private func binding(for venue: Venue) -> Binding<Venue> {
        guard let scrumIndex = viewModel.venues.firstIndex(where: { $0.venueId == venue.venueId }) else {
            fatalError("Can't find scrum in array")
        }
        return $viewModel.venues[scrumIndex]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Confirm your view to `Identifiable`:

```
struct Venue: Codable, Identifiable {
    var id: String {
        venueId
    }
    let venueId: String
    ...
}
```

Or specify `id` directly in `ForEach`:

```swift
ForEach(items, id: \.venueId) {
```